# f:param doesn't send parameters

Tags: jsf, post

In my code, I am sending the id of the photographer to another page. But when i try to get it i get null. 
here is the jsf code:

```
 <h:commandButton action="/viewGallery.xhtml" value="View Gallery" class="btn btn-lg">
        <f:param name="pgid" value="#{logged.logged.photographerid}" />
 </h:commandButton>
```

My bean variables:

```
@ManagedBean(value = "album")
@RequestScoped
public class AlbumDAO {

private CachedRowSetImpl crs;
private Album a;
private ArrayList<Album> aList;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.pgid}")
private int pgid;
```

there where i print the parameters in the bean:

```
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        System.out.println("params = " + params);
        System.out.println("params.get(pgid) = " + params.get("pgid"));
```

and i get the following when i print:

```
     INFO:   params = {j_idt7=j_idt7, j_idt7:j_idt15=Go to profile,  javax.faces.ViewState=6834092215913674538:3363757559364464357}
     INFO:   params.get(pgid) = null
```

Can somebody help me? It used to work but stopped now and I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f:param does send the parameters. Unfortunately it sends the parameters as they were before the action started.

One would expect (at least I did) it would do the action and calculate the parameters and then does the redirect, but the value of f:param is already calculated before the action starts (so often there is null, 0 or something similar in the parameters) and the redirect does not reflect the action outcome.

If you need to update outcome of the action based on the resolution, you need to initiate the redirect from the action itself. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593832/jsf-how-to-redirect-from-backing-bean-to-a-url-dynamically-constructed-in-the-ba) how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

<f:param/> should work. but there is an alternative way to pass paramater. try that

```
<h:button outcome="/viewGallery.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;pgid=#{logged.logged.photographerid}" value="View Gallery" class="btn btn-lg">
</h:button>
```