# Action method does not wait for Action Listener method to finish JSF

Tags: jsf, action, actionlistener

Here are the methods in the bean A:

```
@Transactional
public void updateBO() {

   boolean hasLinkedReq = true;

   update();

   if(hasLinkedReq) {
      showDialog();
   }
}

private void update() {

   // do some stuff
}

public void showDialog() {
  //shows confirmDialog
}
```

Here are the methods in the bean B:

```
public void saveChanges() {
    updateBO();
}

@Transactional
public String close() {
    // save something to database
    return "pretty:requests";
}
```

and this is in the xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton id="confirmSaveCloseBtn"
            value="#{msg['closeunsaved.btn.saveclose']}"
            actionListener="#{productRequest.saveChanges}"
            action="#{productRequest.close}"
            oncomplete="confirmCloseUnsaved.hide()" 
            disabled="#{not requestChecklist.hasWritePermission()}" />
```

So, the method showDialog() is not called. Or at least it is not called before the redirection. When I try to redirect in new window, I see that showDialog() is displayed in the first window, but after the redirection.

Can you help me to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the redirect takes place? Or, is the listener simply not invoked p:commandButton? Inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593832/jsf-how-to-redirect-from-backing-bean-to-a-url-dynamically-constructed-in-the-ba

Comment: HI, yes I am sure, because it displays the correct page when the command button is clicked. The problem is that it does it too early, before the action listener completes.

Comment: So, `saveChanges()` in turn invokes an `@Asynchronous` EJB method or so?

Comment: Well, saveChanges invokes another EJB method: m_mergeRequestDataBean.updateBO(), which invokes another method updateBOData(false). Up to here everything is ok. After that in saveChanges there is a condition based on what another dialog will display or not. So, the problem is that dialog is not displayed. It is displayed after redirection. I know that, because I've tried to redirect in another window. The dialog is displayed in the first window,  after redirection to the second one.

Comment: Edit the question to describe the problem, not the assumption.

Comment: Hello, BalusC, I have edited the question. I hope that it is more understandable now :).

Comment: So .. After reading it 3 times, I gather that you expected that `saveChanges()` method would immediately proceed to render response phase, skipping `close()` method, and then render and show the confirm dialog to the enduser. Then, when the enduser presses "OK" button in the confirm dialog and thus fires a brand new HTTP request, you expect the `close()` method only then being called? Why are you then attempting to invoke the both methods in the very same button which should only open the dialog? This is just a logic mistake.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I was trying to make a redirection on the wrong button. Thank you very much for your help. I would like to give you a positive vote. Can you answer the question, so I can do it :)